# Meaning of the word 'linear' in mathematics

Tags: soft-question

What exactly does 'linear' mean.  For example, Hilbert space is a  linear space. What is the difference between a linear and a 'non-linear' space. I am starting a self-study of linear algebra so this word is extremely important, but what exactly does it mean (especially in linear algebra).

Comment: "Hilbert space is linear" doesn't sound right to me; that's either outdated or physicist's terminology. A Hilbert space is a vector space (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), and "linear" in this context is a property of maps between vector spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).

Comment: Royden's text "Real Analysis" uses "linear space" to denote a vector space.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan For many people the term *Linear space* is synonym to *Vector space*, one may argue it is old fashion but who is to decide that it is wrong?

Comment: @tomcuchta There are plenty of examples, [Metric Linear Spaces](http://books.google.se/books/about/Metric_Linear_Spaces.html?id=qVmHL2M5I9oC&redir_esc=y),  [Linear spaces](http://books.google.se/books/about/Linear_spaces.html?id=Btk-AAAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linearity is the property satisfied by a function (i.e. function $f$ is called linear) iff it satisfies the following two properties:

1. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
2. $f(ax)=af(x) $ where $a$ is a constant from the vector field in consideration.

In linear algebra you'll find that **all** linear functions can be represented as a matrix operation and vice versa.

Also, vector space and linear space are the same thing. Just note that term *linear space* is somewhat archaic and not used very much in modern books. So, I'd suggest using vector space instead.

EDIT: As pointed by qiaochu, linear space can also mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_space_(geometry) though I don't think you wanted this answer. I'm just including it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: "Linear space" is ambiguous; it could also refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_space_(geometry) .

Comment: I don't think it's too rare. I have some textbooks published post-2000 C.E. that use the term "linear space" to mean vector space.

Comment: Thank you, excellent answer, and I read the term 'linear space' as a property for Hilbert Space in the book 'Quantum Mechanics: Concepts and Applications' which I believe is just 3 years old.

Comment: Sometimes *affine* linear functions $f(x)=a\cdot x+b$ are simply called *linear* (because their graph is a *line*). The above definition would call such $f$ linear only if $b=0$. Sometimes these two definitions may be cause of ambiguity.

Comment: Linear functions between infinite-dimensional vector spaces cannot be represented by matrices (unless you generalize to infinite matrices, which don't always behave nicely -- and even so you'll have the problem that the vector space does not always a basis that can be described explicitly).

Answer (score 2):

Linearity does have a [precise definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity). A function $f$ is linear if it is homogenous ($\alpha f(x) = f(\alpha  x)$) and additive ($f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$). To keep things concrete, let $\alpha$ in the definition be a real number and imagine $f$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. What do these conditions mean?

Well, consider the value of $f$ at $0$. Since $f(0) = f(0+0) = f(0)+ f(0) = 2f(0)$, we must have that $f(0) = 0$.

Also, for any $x\neq 0$ we have that $f(x) = xf(1)$. So, if we call $f(1) = a$, we've learned that $f(x) = ax$. That is, the 1D functions that satisfy the conditions for linearity are *lines* that pass through $0$. Lines in the plane are very nice objects that we know a lot about.

The power of the definitions above is that they can be generalized in at least two ways. In Linear Algebra, you'll see that for functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}^m$, the conditions of linearity imply many of the nice properties familiar from simple one-dimensional lines in the plane. This turns out to be very useful (and is [taken further](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) as in, just for example, [functional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_analysis)).

If you go further (or maybe later on in the semester, depending on your course), you'll see we can also fruitfully drop our condition that $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

Linear spaces (ie, vector spaces) and functions are very well studied and have many applications across pure and applied mathematics, as well as in the sciences. As a result, you'll sometimes hear people (across engineering and the sciences) speak somewhat more loosely about "problems" which are "linear". In this context, you'll often think of $x$ as an input to some system. A "[linear system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_system)" is one in which when you scale the input by $\alpha$ (say, pedal faster on your bicycle), the output of the system scales by just the same amount (your bike moves faster a proportionate amount). That is, $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$.

A nonlinear system, then, might be one where a tiny change in input results in a huge change in output (you pedal faster and your bicycle explodes). Explosions, turbulence, and the "[butterfly effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect)" are typical examples.

Comment: "Linear" has a precise definition _in linear algebra_. Across mathematics as a whole it less precise -- in particular, much of the time "linear" is used for things that are allowed to contain a constant term, and things _without_ constant terms are called "_homogeneous_ linear" systems (etc.)